# How can I cleanup a botched Truecrypt installation?

Tags: truecrypt, cleanup

I made the mistake of downloading the X64 version of Truecrypt and trying to install it when I'm actually running the 32-bit version of Precise Pangolin.

I want to clean up the files that I am unable to use, but of course I can't just run the uninstall since Truecrypt could not be installed in the first place.

I am new to this but I have spent some time researching the command line.

When I run "locate trucrypt -i" in the terminal I receive several relevant files in the usr/bin and usr/share directories. No "rm" commands work on these listed files--I only get "no such file or directory" back. I'm sure this has something to do with permissions but I don't know what I'm missing here.

Why is it I cannot find these files through the GUI (even when I select "show hidden files") or when I try to navigate to these files via the terminal using cd and ls commands?

How can I remove these files (they are there aren't they?), one way or another, from my system?

Your patience and time are appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install Truecrypt on 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054270/is-it-possible-to-install-truecrypt-on-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

The locate command stores the list of files in a database. So those files could have been deleted, but still show up in the "locate" output. Enter the command `sudo updatedb` to update the database, then run your locate command again.

Answer (score 0):

TrueCrypt doesn't do a very complex installation - no databases are modified when installing. The installation process consists of extracting a bunch of files, and the uninstallation process consists of deleting all those files.

If typing `sudo truecrypt-uninstall.sh` doesn't fix it, just run this series of commands:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/truecrypt*
sudo rm -f /usr/share/applications/truecrypt*
sudo rm -f /usr/share/pixmaps/truecrypt*
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/truecrypt/
```

After that, you may want to reboot (although it might not be necessary,) and then continue with your installation like normal!