# Is it possible to install Truecrypt on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, truecrypt

I have several desktops running 16.04LTS.  I have been anticipating upgrading them to 18.04LTS.  I recently installed 18.04 on a crash dummy machine for testing and it mostly is working quite well.  I downloaded the standard amd iso and installed Ubuntu without disk encryption (or LVM).  This machine happens to have an AMD processor.  All of my other machines use Intel CPUs.

I have quite a few folders that have been encrypted using Truecrypt.  7.1-14 I believe.  The old version in any case.

I see that Truecrypt doesn't seem to be included in the standard distro so I installed it manually.  However, it will not decrypt any of my existing encrypted folders.  As a test, I created a container and then tried to mount it and that also failed.  I won't bother with the various messages I got but suffice to say that Truecrypt is not working on my 18.04 LTS install.

I've read quite a few threads regarding this new distro and I'm wondering if it is a requirement to select full disk encryption when building the OS in order to have TC support.  And either way, is there a method to install TC as a stand alone encryption tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your TrueCrypt installation, close all of TC running instances and  install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install bzr libncurses5-dev gcc debhelper devscripts dpatch
```

Run TC again and you'll see everything works.

TrueCrypt works perfectly in my Ubuntu 18.04 on AMD CPU.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: With all due respect, that's not the question I asked.  I can launch the TC GUI:  V 7.1a-14 in my case.  However, I cannot decrypt any folders that were created on any of my older machines.  I can create new encrypted folders on 18.04 and that "seems" to work however I am unable to decrypt them.  Gives a "failed to set up a loop device" error.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks very much.  If you can tweak your answer to clearly indicate that this is a problem with 18.04 LTS running Truecrypt so that others can find it as a FAQ I will happily give you the points for a correct answer.

NOTE TO UBUNTU ENGINEERING:  Apparently, these modules need to be added to the standard distro...something that the morons who downvoted my question don't understand.

Very much appreciate your help on this @Wiking!

Comment: Perhaps, but that statement was also true for 16.04 LTS as well as other previous distros.  TC stopped being developed right about when Win10 was released.  However....  it's still an excellent encryption tool.  Robust, bug-free and still widely in use by many *NIX folks.  Adding the modules you mentioned to the 18.04 distro seems like a trivial amount of work.  Failing to do that will only cause a lot of unnecessary work and future questions like mine...  which is why at a very minimum, making your answer part of an easy to find FAQ would be very valuable.  Just asking Eng to consider.

Comment: I guess the real solution would be to just continue adding TC to the standard LTS distributions as Ubuntu has done for lo these many years.